# Как настроить алиасы в storybook?

Tags: webpack, storybook

Пытаюсь уже полдня настроить алиасы в сторибуке, кидает ошибку Cannot find module '@/shared', что я не так делаю?

```
//tsconfig
   "paths": {
        "@/*": ["./src/*"],
        "@assets*": ["./src/shared/ui/assets*"]
    }

//stories

//такие импорты работают
// import type { TLoaderUIProps } from '../shared/UI/loader/loader'
// import { LoaderUI } from '../shared/UI/loader/loader'

//такие импорты не работают
    import type { TLoaderUIProps } from '@/shared'
    import { LoaderUI } from '@/shared'

//main storybook
    webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    //подскажите как корректно вписать импорты, пробовал и с плагином tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin и через явное указание пути - все равно не работает  
    }
```